# Неправильно работает LEFT JOIN pgsql

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql, join

У меня есть 2 таблицы. investment_project и passport_financing.
Мне нужно вывести содержание первой таблицы и соответствующие записи из второй. Если во второй таблице нет записи по внешнему ключу, выводить NULL

```
SELECT 
  ip.id_investment_project, 
  pf.total_passport_financing_plan 
FROM 
  managingcp.investment_project ip 
  LEFT JOIN managingcp.passport_financing pf ON ip.id_investment_project = pf.id_investment_project_passport 
WHERE 
  pf.id_financial_indicators_capital_construction = (
    SELECT 
      id_financial_indicators_capital_construction 
    FROM 
      nsi.financial_indicators_capital_construction 
    WHERE 
      cod_fin_ind = '1'
  )
```

По итогу у меня вместо 5000+ тысяч записей выводит 12 (количество соотвтв. записей из второй таблицы)

Comment: WHERE по правой таблице превращает LEFT JOIN в INNER. Перемести условие из WHERE в ON.

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0):

Это потому, что вы наложили условие на присоединяемую таблицу через `WHERE`. Накладывайте условия только через `LEFT JOIN ... ON ...`, если хотите, чтобы в итоговой выдаче были все записи из левой таблицы. В `ON` вы можете использовать сложное условие через `AND`, `OR` и скобки.